# Python Replace Two Headers with One

Tags: python, pandas, header, row

I currently have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
     | Unnamed:1|Unnamed:2 |Unnamed:3 |
     | Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | 
0    | Data     | Data     | Data     |
1    | Data     | Data     | Data     |
2    | Data     | Data     | Data     |
3    | Data     | Data     | Data     |
```

I've been using the following code unsuccessfully as it replaces the header with the index [0] row:

```
new_header = df.iloc[0] 
df = df[1:] 
df.columns = new_header
```

Ideally the new dataframe would look like:

```
     | Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | 
0    | Data     | Data     | Data     |
1    | Data     | Data     | Data     |
2    | Data     | Data     | Data     |
3    | Data     | Data     | Data     |
```

Answer (score 1):

You are dealing with Multiindex columns. If you want to keep just the second header line, this would be enough: `df.columns = df.columns.get_level_values(1)`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your data is being read in as having a `pd.MultiIndex` column. This means that functionally each of your column labels is actually a tuple of values:

```
[("Unnamed:1", "Column 1"), ("Unnamed:2", "Column 2"), ...]
```

To fix this you can drop the 0th level of your columns using `df.droplevel(0, axis=1)` method. This will drop the first element of each of those aforementioned `tuples`. We specify `axis=1` because we want to drop the 0th level of the column index, and not the row index.

Snippet to try:

```
df = df.droplevel(0, axis=1)
```

Reproducible snippet:

```
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(
    [["Unnamed:1", "Unnamed:2", "Unnamed:3"], 
     ["Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3"]]
)
data = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

print(df)
  Unnamed:1 Unnamed:2 Unnamed:3
   Column 1  Column 2  Column 3
0         1         2         3
1         4         5         6
2         7         8         9
```

Now using `.droplevel(...)`:

```
df = df.droplevel(0, axis=1)
print(df)

   Column 1  Column 2  Column 3
0         1         2         3
1         4         5         6
2         7         8         9
```